# Stuck on "Get Started" page of Google App Engine. "gcloud app deploy" fails

Tags: google-app-engine

I am stuck on the first page of instructions for Google App Engine

https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/start/reception

I downloaded and installed the cloud SDK.

"gcloud init" worked.

I am stuck at "Deploy to App Engine".

When I type "gcloud app deploy" in Terminal, I get two errors.

"ERROR: An app.yaml (or appengine-web.xml) file is required to deploy this directory as an App Engine application. Create an app.yaml file using the directions at [https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml"](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml%22)

The page it says to go to does not give directions for creating the file. What is the command? Also, why is this error happening at all? If I follow the instructions on the Get Started page, I should not get an error. Some instructions must be missing or something not working when I install the SDK.

The second error I get is "ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) [/Users/chucky] could not be identified as a valid source directory or file."

Again, there must be instructions missing because I am following them.

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0AyT.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the link:

> https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/start/reception

First, you need to download the resources. You can use the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#windows), [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/deploying-an-app-engine-app), directly download from github or other terminal to download the resources files. For example, you want to deploy a Python app using Cloud SDK in Windows OS:

1. [Install](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#windows) and open Cloud SDK.
2. Copy the resources file from [github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples):

**From Cloud SDK run:**

```
git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples
```

3. Go to directory of your application files:

```
cd python-docs-samples/appengine/standard_python3/hello_world
```

4. Deploy and browse your application

**Deploy using the command**:

```
gcloud app deploy --project PROJECTID
```

**Browse using the command**:

```
gcloud app browse --project PROJECTID
```

If you see the Hello World! you've successfully deployed your application.

Answer (score 0):

`gcloud app deploy` is for deploying a project. This means you need to have a folder with a sample project. The project will need to have an `app.yaml` file. Essentially, the steps are

1. Download and install the Google Cloud SDK
2. Run `gcloud init` to initialize the SDK (this makes you to login to Google and grant access to gcloud to your account; also sets up your default project)
3. Create your project (or copy an existing one) where project is your App i.e. the application you are working on. This project should have an `app.yaml` file.
4. Then deploy your project to production by running `gcloud app deploy`. You first have to change directory to your project folder. If you don't want to do this, you have to specify the full path to your `app.yaml` file.

An alternative for steps 3 - 4 is to use a Graphical User Interface (GUI) like one from us - https://nocommandline.com . You just **click a button** to create a new project and it will create a shell project ('hello world') with all the necessary files. To deploy your project, you also click another button 'Deploy' and it will take care of deploying your project.